# Asp-fallback and (custom) dependend scripts

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, fallback

I am using Asp.Net Core 2.2 and would like to load common js libraries from a cdn, and fallback to local resources in intranet situations where the cdn is not reachable.

The fallback itself works, but I have custom scripts that use jquery and fail when the cdn resource fails, although jquery gets loaded from the local source.
This are the script tags I used:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"
  asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
  asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=">
</script>

<script src="~/js/myScript.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

My script fails with `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. I assume that is because the failback resource loaded later than my script, because typing $ in the prompt yields function().

Additional info:
I also get errors in the js log stating that the integrity hash is incorrect. This does not bother me (yet), since the fallback libraries work.

Also it takes a very long time before the page noticed that the cdn was not reachable and loaded the local fallback (almost 2 minutes).
To block the cdn I added a temporary entry in my local dns file (hosts in windows).

What do I have to do to make my own scripts work with the fallback?

Answer (score 1):

Last I checked, there was really no known solution for this.
[image]

In regards to the integrity hash being incorrect, this is possibly due to the files not being binary equal. You can bypass that integrity check if wanted, by setting asp-suppress-fallback-integrity to true.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"
  asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
  asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  asp-suppress-fallback-integrity="true">
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. I have added asp-suppress-fallback-integrity="true" since the creation of this question. The main issue is still there. I cannot use a cdn, bc the whole page would fail when the cdn cannot be accessed.

Comment: I will look into other ways of solving this. Without the asp-tag-helper there should be a way of solving the requirement of using a cdn and falling back on local resources.